# Python requests - Automated queries

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, recaptcha

I've been trying to write a script that logs into an account and grabs data for the last few days, but I can't manage to get it to login and I always encounter this error message:

> Your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect
>   our users, we can't process your request right now.

I assume this is the error message provided by ReCaptcha v2, I'm using a ReCaptcha service, but I even get this error message on my machine locally without or with a proxy.

I've tried different proxies, different proxy sources, headers, user agents, nothing seems to work. I've used requests, and I still get this error message, Selenium and still get this error message and my own browser and still get this error message.

What kind of workaround is there to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

So I am writing this answer from my general experience with web scraping.

> Different web application react differently under different conditions, the solutions I am giving here may not fully solve your problem.

Here are a few work around methodologies:

- Use selenium only and set a proper window screen size. Most modern web apps identify users based on window size and user agent. In your case it is not recommended going for other solutions such as requests which do not allow proper handling of window size.
- Use a modern valid user agent (`Mozilla 5.0 compatible`). Usually a Chrome browser > 60.0 UA will work good.
- Keep chaining and changing proxies with each interval of xxx requests (depends upon your work load).
- Use a single user agent for a specific proxy. If your UA keeps changing for a specific IP, Recaptcha will grab you as automated.
- Handle cookies properly. Make sure the cookies set by the server are sent with subsequent requests (for a single proxy).
- Use time gap between requests. Use `time.sleep()` to delay consecutive requests. Usually a time delay of 2 seconds would be enough.

I know this would considerably slow down your work, but Recaptcha is something that which is designated to prevent such automated queries/scraping.

Comment: `window size` and `user agent` was perfect. Any strong reason for _user agent_ `Mozilla 5.0` compatible and _Chrome_ browser `> 60.0 UA`? Any documentation?

Comment: @DebanjanB, you see some apps respond with a warning, "Please upgrade your browser to latest version of Firefox/Chrome to Continue", when you're making subsequent requests with an outdated browser, isn't it obvious to pull up a Recaptcha?

Comment: Hmmm, food for thoughts :)